# BizTalk WCF Send Port error - The header 'CoordinationContext' was not understood

Tags: wcf, biztalk, wcf-binding, biztalk-2009

I have a WCF-WSHttp Send Port set up with Enable Transactions checked, and I'm getting the following error when a message is sent:

```
The header 'CoordinationContext' from the namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/10/wscoor' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.
```

If I uncheck the Enable Transactions box, the message is processed successfully.  Can anyone help me get this working with transaction support?

Here's the binding info from the service's web.config (transactionFlow is set to true):

```
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="serviceBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a thought, but you might try this with a non-biztalk WCF client first to ensure that transaction flow is set up correctly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733943.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the service itself.  Although the bindings were configured properly with transactionFlow="true", the service contract was missing the following attribute to explicitly allow transactions:

```
[System.ServiceModel.TransactionFlowAttribute(System.ServiceModel.TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the setup of MSDTC, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752261.aspx

Also check the event log for MSDTC related errors.